# App crashing when no connectivity to net

Tags: android, android-asynctask, crash, jsoup, connectivity

I'm trying to get some info from a website (some text) in my app. The problem is that sometimes my method doesn't work. I have built this and use it for checking for internet connectivity:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

However, sometimes phones tell the app that tere is indeed an internet connection, when there is no actual stable one, and then the app crashes.

The actual refresh of the info is in an Async task and is executed like this, where crackerTask is my async task:

```
if (this.isNetworkAvailable()) {

        crackerTask.execute(TESTSTRINGURL);}

     else {
        Toast.makeText(NewsAndAnnouncements.this,
                "No web connectivity. Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

How can I avoid the crash of the program when my phone tells the app there is internet, while there isn't?

EDIT:
here's the async task if that helps.

```
private class NewsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog dialog1;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(NewsAndAnnouncements.this, "Loading",
                "Fetching data from web...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arguments) {
        // extract arguments
        String newsurl = arguments[0];
        //
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(newsurl).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements myElements = doc.getElementsByClass("news_list");
        string1 = myElements.toString();
        Log.i("ELEMENTS HTML", string1);
        return string1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // super.onPostExecute(result);
        FINALSTRING = result;
        tv2.setText(FINALSTRING);
        if (dialog1 != null) {
            if (dialog1.isShowing()) {
                dialog1.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also, I can't really tell you the log results because I can't really simulate the situation of having an active network but poor internet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you move the check for connectivity inside of the AsyncTask then? As opposed to checking before and then running the task to find out you don't have it, why not check inside the AsyncTask DIRECTLY before you actually do anything with the internet, inside of `doInBackground`.

***EDIT***: I think I may have figured out what's wrong. You set `Document doc = null` and then in your try statement, you set `doc` to be whatever you get from the internet. However, if that doesn't work, your `doc` remains null AND you keep going, assuming `doc` has something in it. Make your `doInBackground` look like this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arguments) {
    // extract arguments
    String newsurl = arguments[0];
    //
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(newsurl).get();
        Elements myElements = doc.getElementsByClass("news_list");
        string1 = myElements.toString();
    Log.i("ELEMENTS HTML", string1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        string1 = null;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        string1 = null;
    }

    return string1;
}
```

And in your `onPostExecute`, check to see if `result` is null and do something accordingly.

Comment: will give it a try, though i don't know how that would help the problem?

Comment: You pretty much described what's happening: it seems the user has spotty internet. You'll have connection one second and the next it's gone, which does happen. The gap between checking for connection and doing the work might be too far apart, though I could be wrong. Also, can you post your logcat so we can see exactly what the problem is?

Comment: the problem is i don't have spotty internet at home. i can't simulate what happens around my computer because both the mobile and wifi are good and thus - can't get the logcat on this error :D (first world problems) i want the following sollution - when the internet goes down WHILE already refreshing i don't want the app to force close.

Comment: May have found a more useful solution for you. Updated my answer.

Comment: thank you! will give it a try in an hour or two and will tell you if it works. It looks very logical by the way, it would be sweet if that's the problem.

Comment: that worked. stupid me! 

thank you a lot for the cooperation :)

Answer (score 0):

method to check the internet connection

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet()
{
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
```

and in the needed activity call like that

```
cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(push.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);

        return;
    }
```

Comment: I will try it. If it works can you elaborate on why this is better? I want to understand the problem better.